# How to Record the Video through Camera, And Record the SystemTimeStamp over the Video

Tags: android, video, camera, timestamp, mediarecorder

I need to design a app.That when Record the Video through Camera,Show and Record the SystemTimeStamp above the Video.
Can it work with current Android Frameworks?
If can, How can i do this?
Thanks for anybody to read this!

Comment: You might be interested in my answer to a similiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65505230/361413).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Follow the procedure below.
1. Capture video byte array (of each frame).
2. Now create bitmap from byte array.
3. Use link below to overlay text over bitmap.
4. Save those bitmaps to create video.
```

[Text Overlay bitmap.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184506/adding-text-to-a-bitmap-in-memory-in-android)

Comment: Hi,Bhupinder.Thank you very much for your reply!But I'm so sorry that I don't know how to complete the step 4.Could you give me some suggestion or links to study this knowledge?However Thanks!

Comment: Here are few tutorials see below

http://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Example_Android_Video


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817742/how-can-i-capture-a-video-recording-on-android

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893072/getting-frames-from-video-image-in-android/2164906#2164906

Comment: Thanks for your patient!I'll look these carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow a two-stage approach. First, record the video using the [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) API (which IMO is easier to use than MediaCodec - the [Camera2 example](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2video/Camera2VideoFragment.java) is quite useful). Second, post-process the video with
Taner Şener's wonderful [mobile-ffmpeg](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg), where you can simply add millisecond timestamps in the lower right corner with a command like:

```
FFmpeg.execute("-i \"" + pathToVideo + "\" -vf drawtext=\"fontsize=60:fontcolor=yellow@0.8:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.8:boxborderw=10:text='%
{e\\:" + startMillis + "+t*1000}':x=(w-text_w+6.8*max_glyph_w):y=(h-text_h)\" \"" + pathToVideo.replace(".mp4", "_overlaid.mp4" + "\""));
```