# android - MediaCodec record video with timestamp on each video frame

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I need to record video with timestamp on each video frame. I see a example in [cts](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/kitkat-release/tests/tests/media) which use InputSurace.java and OutputSurface.java to connect Decoder and Encoder to transcode video files. Is it possible to reuse these two android java class to implement a timestamp video recorder?

I try to use OutputSurface as Camera preview output and use InputSurface as MediaCodec Encoder input but sounds like only record 2 or 3 frames then it hang there forever!

Comment: You might be interested in another approach using MediaRecorder and mobile-ffmpeg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65505434/361413).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your time and explore this [link](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java) to get an idea how to feed the Camera preview into a video file. Once you are confident about the mechanism, you should be able to feed the `MediaCodec` input surface with some kind of OpenGL magic to put extra graphics on the top of the Camera's preview. I would recommend to tweak the example code's `drawExtra()` as a start.

Comment: link expired, Can you kindly share again

Comment: Done. Thanks for letting me know.